# What is the meaning of the green curved arrow in the Visual Studio code editor?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

If you go to this webpage, and scroll down:

http://www.unauthorised-access.com/category/nettiers/

You see a green U-turn like arrow. Does anyone know what this means? I read somewhere, a long time ago, it has something to do with threading and multi-threaded code but I can't remember.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I think that's just showing a line break.  The line with the green arrow should be on the same line as the one above, but it's been split because it is too wide for the page.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this simply a symbol to indicate that the line was wrapped by the source code formatter?